# How to get the Channel Type or Category of each YouTube channel using YouTube API?

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I am new to using the YouTube API. 
I am trying to get the Channel Category of each channel, but I don't know how to make a request to get the category.

I will give an example:
http://socialblade.com/youtube/user/pewdiepie

As you can see on the Socialblade statistic of pewdiepie there is a "CHANNEL TYPE" above and the channel type or category of pewdiepie is "Games" but how did Socialblade request for that?

I hope you can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well the v3 API doesn't have a category for each channel, so they probably use a formula on the videos found in the channel to determine the overall category.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels