# YouTube API : Getting list of channels of a specific genre

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to get list of channels of a specific genre in my App using YouTube API.

For Example -
I want to get list of all comedy channels on YouTube in my App.

Is this possible , if yes than How ?

Comment: You have to acknowledge that YouTube does not associate a video genre to any given channel. That's because YouTube does not restrict videos to be uploaded on a channel to belong to a certain genre. That's to say that any given channel is allowed to contain videos irrespective of genre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube's V3 API doesn't have a category for each channel.

Take a look at this similar question: [How to get the Channel Type or Category of each YouTube channel using YouTube API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706288/how-to-get-the-channel-type-or-category-of-each-youtube-channel-using-youtube-ap)

YouTube documentation for this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels

The YouTube API does however show if videos and by extension channels make videos for kids.